# SQL query to count number of emails sent using regular expressions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need a SQL query which can count the number of emails sent out using regular expressions

for example

Column Name: SENT_EMAIL Table Name: EMAILS

If SENT_EMAIL has
abc@gmail.com; xyz@hotmail.com
then count should be 2

If SENT_EMAIL has
abc@gmail.com 
then count should be 1

I am sure we can use '@' as a reference to count the number of emails within the SENT_EMAIL column but I am unable to think how.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
select e.SENT_EMAIL, length(e.SENT_EMAIL) - length(replace(e.SENT_EMAIL, '@', '')) as mail_cnt from EMAILS e
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, use [`REGEXP_COUNT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions147.htm#sthref1418)

```
select regexp_count(sent_email, '[[:alnum:]]@[[:alnum:]]')
  from emails
```

I'm checking where there's something other than an `@` there, to ensure you only count e-mails. It's technically incorrect as e-mails can have a lot of other characters other than alpha-numerics so it depends on your data. If you only want to count the number of `@` in a row then just do that.

```
select regexp_count(sent_email, '@')
  from emails
```